# detect java/jre on IE6 using javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, java

I want to know if there is an alternative way to find out if JRE is installed on IE6, besides using the Java deployment toolkit (getJRE()). I tried to use `navigator.javaEnabled()`, but it returns true no matter if JRE is installed or not. Moreover, `navigator.plugins[i].name` returns undefined object on IE6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an applet:

```
System.getProperty("java.version");
System.getProperty("java.vendor");
```

Then you need to get that data from javascript using LiveConnect.

EDIT: 
I founded a post with this method in this [link](http://www.spiration.co.uk/post/1186/Java-detect-brower,-JVM-vendor,-Java-version-etc)

Answer (score 0):

This isnt a nice looking but it works for me on ie6 you could try and catch if error and then even use the var defining the java object as well to check again.

```
try {
var j = new java.util.Date();
}
catch(err) {
document.write('no java'); // example
}

alert(j) // undefined
```

there the page RIA Deployment Advice

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html